# How to determine the derivative of $\partial F(t,x,x')= \Big(a(t,x)x' - \frac{c}{2}(x')^2\Big)e^{-rt}$ with respect to x

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am given
$\partial F(t,x,x')= \Big(a(t,x)x' - \frac{c}{2}(x')^2\Big)e^{-rt}$

How do i determine
$\frac{\partial F(t,x(t),x'(t))}{\partial x}$

I can't seem to figure it out

I tried, but do not think it is correct $a'_{x(t)}(t,x(t))x'(t)e^{-rt} $

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, give a context to your question, and say what you have tried to get a solution. If you do not, your question might be closed.

Comment: ... and please, use MathJax.